# Index File in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my htaccess file I have the following redirections:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule index.html$ Controller/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I want index.html (which does not exist) to be redirected to my controller.
index.php (which exists) should be my home page.

Now, my homepage is not working when typing http://www.domain.com/ in my browser. That URL redirects to my controller.
http://www.domain.com/index.php works fine, bringing my homepage.

How do I set index.php as my index file keeping my redirection for the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your situation correctly, you just want to specify [`DirectoryIndex`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) in your `.htaccess` file so that it only points to `index.php`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Between that and your rules, that leads to the following URL to file mappings:

```
http://www.example.com/           -> /index.php
http://www.example.com/index.php  -> /index.php
http://www.example.com/index.html -> /Controller/index.php
```

Comment: Additionally, for future reference, this is somewhat more of a [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Tim. That didn't do it, I still have the same issue. I'll ask on ServerFault.